# Joining Lists of Lists in Python in a specific manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, join, nested-lists

Given two very large lists (about 50K records)     `list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]`     and      `list2 = [['a','r','t'],['d','e','n']]`      . How to obtain      `list3 = [['a','b','c','r','t'],['d','e','f','e','n']]`

Here I'm joining by comapring the first character of the second list's sublists and taking only one of them in final list

I am new to python 
I tried

```
i=0
final=[]
    while (i<len(list1)) :
        for row in list2 :
            if(list1[i][0]==list2[0]) :
                final= row + list[i][1:]

    i+=1
```

But this does not work

Comment: Hello and welcome! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Post your attempt and we'll tell you how to fix it or do it more efficiently.

Comment: Please also explain why the two lists in the result only have five elements each.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here.
Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
list2 = [['a','r','t'],['d','e','n']]

print([x+y[1:] for x,y in zip(list1,list2)])
```

Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), and [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function this can be done rather quickly.

Edited based on comments, use an `if` case to only allow certain things through:

```
list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
list2 = [['a','r','t'],['d','e','n']]

print([x+y[1:] for x,y in zip(list1,list2) if x[0] == y[0]])
```

Comment: Thank you, I am new here.
And sorry for not posting my attempt before

Comment: What if I want to join using the condition that the first element of the sublists are same

Comment: What happens if they aren't the same ?

Comment: It does not print them, loop continues